# Unable to detect any error but my programs hangs

Tags: c#, detection, infinite-loop

For example i have to matrices

```
  Allocation Matrix

  0 0 1 0
  2 0 0 1
  0 1 2 0

  Request matrix
  2 0 0 1
  1 0 1 0
  2 1 0 0

  Resources in Existence: 4 2 3 1
  Available resources: 2 1 0 0
```

My Code

```
            for (w = 0; w < TRows; )
            {
                if (Finish[w] == 0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    for (x = 0; x < TColumns; x++)
                    {
                        if (A[x] >= Request[w, x])
                            flag = flag + 1;
                    }
                    if (flag == TColumns)
                    {
                        T[y] = w;
                        Finish[w] = 1;
                        for (x = 0; x < TRows; x++)
                        {
                            A[x] = A[x] + Allocation[w, x];
                        }
                        y = y + 1;
                        w = -1;
                        //break;
                    }
                    w++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: you should definitely step through it with debugger.

Comment: It would help to know where the program is when you pause it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use more descriptive variable names. Your code is almost impossible to read. I did spot at least one problem though:

```
for (w = 0; w < TRows; )
{
    if (Finish[w] == 0)
    {
        /* snip */
        w++;
        /* snip */
    }
}
```

If `Finish[w]` (whatever that means) ever ends up being something else than `0`. `w` will never get incremented and you've got yourself an infinite loop. And if it was always `0`, you wouldn't need that test to begin with. Something is wrong with your logic here.

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't look right.

```
for (w = 0; w < TRows; )
```

How will that loop ever finish if `Finish[0]` is non-zero?

Did you try Debug-Break-All in Visual Studio to see where it was hanging?